# Highcharts stacked column chart with with irregular time intervals possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to produce a stacked column chart with a timeline on the x-axis where every series does NOT necessarily have a data point matching the date in question.  I am able to produce a column chart with multiple columns per data point, but I really want a stacked chart.  The data for the chart is JSON which I can manipulate the format of as need be.

```
var options = {
              chart: {
                  renderTo: 'timeline',
                  zoomType: 'x',
                  type: 'column'
              },
              title: {
                  text: 'Releases'
              },
              yAxis: {
                  title: {
                    text: 'Count'
                  }
              },
              xAxis: {
                  type: 'datetime'
              },
              legend: {
                  enabled: true
              },
              series: []
          };

/* 
Following URL returns json like:

{
    "rows": {
        "dynamicCategory1": {
            "0": {
                "count": "7",
                "unix_date": "1344225600"
            },
            "3": {
                "count": "2",
                "unix_date": "1344312000"
            }
        },
        "dynamicCategory2": {
            "5": {
                "count": "7",
                "unix_date": "1344225600"
            },
            "7": {
                "count": "2",
                "unix_date": "1345003200"
            }
        }
    }
}

*/

$.getJSON("/mydatainjsonformat/", function(data) {

  $.each(data.rows, function(key, val) {
    var series = { data: [] };

    series.name = key;

    $.each(val, function(key2, val2) {
      var x = parseFloat(val2.unix_date * 1000);
      var y = parseFloat(val2.count);

      series.data.push([x, y]);

    });

    options.series.push(series);

  });

  $(function () {
      var chart1;
      $(document).ready(function() {
          chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
      });
  });
});
```

Theoretically I could alter the data to include a 0 for each category that doesn't have a value for a given date, then make the dates the categories - but is that the right way to go here?  Won't that screw up the time on the x-axis?  Any direction greatly appreciated.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyqPj/123/)

Comment: Can you generate a fiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: jsfiddle added above and here: http://jsfiddle.net/KyqPj/123/

Answer (score 2):

So: after much pain and suffering, I was missing this stanza which needed to be passed as configuration for my chart:

```
              plotOptions: {
                column: {
                  stacking: 'normal'
                },
```

and even that took me a long time to find, because I had that stanza in there for most of my testing, but had NOT camelCased plotOptions.  *bangs head on keyboard multiple times and weeps*

It's working great now.  Other hassle: to get jsfiddle to return json to you over an AJAX call ('/echo/json/'), you MUST POST to it.  Took me a while to determine why the heck $.getJSON wasn't working also.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is that you want to achieve something like this.

You have something like event starting on X date and you want to draw line up to Y date.

So, You are trying to use this using Stacked Bar chart so, you get lines across Y Axis.

If I am correct then I would suggest you to use Highstock, It is one of the library developed by [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com).

`Highstock` is preferred API to  create timeline charts.

I have created a sample fiddle which help you to start. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/mhardik/YmRUg/

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to show the breakdown on a given day by number of different categories, when the number and variety of categories could change over time.  I found an example last night that is basically what I am trying to achieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/DjHDW/100/

Now I just need to figure out how what I have and what is there are different.

Comment: @user1720033: Does this helped you ? Please read FAQ for better usage of SO.

Comment: as indicated above, No, it didn't help - I ended up solving my own issues (also as indicated above).  Appreciate the effort.